# configuring grub at boot up

Tags: linux, boot, grub

How do I configure grub settings during boot process?What commands can I use at that time?I know I can change the settings in grub.conf or grub.cfg file but I want to do it at the time of booting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the 'e' key to edit a GRUB entry at startup. That's a pretty well documented process : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Editing_the_GRUB_2_Menu_During_Boot